# BEA-101020 error on weblogic 11g running axis2 on jrockit 1.6_024/linux

Tags: wsdl, oracle11g, weblogic, apache-axis

```
we have axis2 (1.5.1)web service deployed on weblogic 11g running on jrockit 1.6._024/linux boxes.
we get <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1342771457231> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@470808509[app:npv-websvc module:/ path: spec-version:null]] Servlet failed with Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.nodeListItem(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.item(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOM2Writer.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOM2Writer.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOM2Writer.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOM2Writer.print(Unknown Source)


Axis2 JIRA had a recommended bug fix (URL below) but this is happening more frequently after we upgraded weblogic 9 to weblogic 11g. any patch recommended by oracle ?
```

The above null pointer does a stack overflow and the whole weblogic instance comes down.

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4517

Appreciate experts help here !
```